# Can't add header to request in RETROFIT

Tags: java, android, rest, http, retrofit

I use retrofit to make REST API calls. To authenticate there is used API KEY which I want include within header. I tried two approaches:

Add Annotation within interface method:

```
@GET("discover/movie")
Call<PopularMovies> getPopularMovies(@Query("release_date.gte") String release_date_gte,
                                           @Query("release_date.lte") String release_date_lte,
                                           @Query("page") int page,
                                            @Header("Authorization") String api_key)
```

The second is to use interceptor

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.API_KEY))
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
```

Neither of those add header to the request. Could anyone help figure it out? 
Thanks

Comment: first approach should work. I do it in the same manner use @FormUrlEncoded on top

Comment: I do as the second approach, and it's working also

Comment: Did you do any extra configurations?
This is how I build retrofit object in the second approach, is this good?
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT_URL)
                                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                                .client(httpClient)
                                .build();

Comment: How did you check that the header was not added? With a logging interceptor? By watching the network traffic (e. g. Wireshark)? Or server-side?